# Can I stop using CSS3 vendor prefixes on border-radius and box-shadow?

Tags: web-standards, css

I’m noticing on [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) that all modern versions of major browsers used in the US now support the non vendor prefixed versions of the CSS3 properties: [border-radius](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) and [box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow). Is it safe to stop using the vendor prefixes for both of those properties now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on your user-base. While newer versions of popular browsers do support non-prefixed versions, older versions do not. You can't be sure that all your users have already updated or will ever update their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> You can't be sure that all your users have already updated or will ever update their browsers.

This is true, but how can I hope that some will even have those browsers which support -vendor-border-radius? I have to do some more research, but I plan to sanitize my stylesheets from this clutter. Unless I get really serious problems reported.

Thinking this way, we should better stick to table layout, or maybe do some browser identification, and serve different stylesheets for every browser. And the rounded corners will be in background gifs, right? I think, if someone has a browser from the stone age, he should be prepared to have a worse experience when browsing.

As long as the page works, and the layout doesn't fall all apart, I opt for avoiding unnecessary hacks. OK, it also depends on your target audience - if this is an advertisement
page of a web design studios, then put in all possible -moz-, -o-, -webkit- and -ms-. You can expect, that everybody will test it with *bad* browsers ;)

If your page is a web application, where people want to get something done, and you want it to load quickly and do what your users want - it is another situation. So, if you have something that *degrades gracefully*, I'd dare to cut corners on users of out of date WWW clients.